# Android Debug -> Disconnected from the target VM

Tags: android, debugging, disconnect

Suddenly it is not possible to debug my android device. After a few seconds the device disconnects and i get the following message: "Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:49504', transport: 'socket'
I am using a Zebra Scanner.

I didn't change the code since the last time that i worked on that app.

I deselected all breakpoints.
I tried different activites.
Even by just starting the app in debug mode, it disconnets after a few seconds.
Running the app and attatching the debugger has the same result.

Comment: Did you find any soulotion ?